# Read video frame with OpenCV to specified pointer (C++)

Tags: c++, opencv, pointers, memory-management, video-capture

Is there a way to read a video frame with videocapture and specify where it should go in memory?  Let's say given I have a pointer char *p and have preallocated the correct amount of memory for the frame, can I read in the frame to p's address?

Answer (score 2):

`cv::Mat` is designed to handle memory management of images automatically, but it can also be used with externally allocated buffers.  To do this, pass in a pointer to the external buffer to the [`Mat` constructor](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a51615ebf17a64c968df0bf49b4de6a3a).

Make sure the buffer size, Mat size, and type (channels, depth, etc.) match the output coming out of VideoCapture.

Example:

```
unsigned char *data; // Points to buffer of appropriate size.
cv::VideoCapture cap; // A valid capture

// This only allocates the Mat header with a reference to "data"
cv::Mat frame {
    rows,
    cols,
    CV_8UC3, // image type, here 3-channel, 8 bits per channel, unsigned
    data
};
cap >> frame;  // Image data stored into buffer at "data"
```

Comment: Change: {} => ()